# Hyper-V virtual machine can't be migrated to a specific host in the cluster

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, cluster, live-migration

I have a three-node Hyper-V cluster running on Windows Server 2008 R2 which is working quite flawlessly: there are no errors, live migration works, all hosts can and will happily run all virtual machines, and so on.

But one specific virtual machinee is trying to make me go mad: it works on two nodes of the cluster, but not on the third one.

Whenever I try to move the VM to that node, be it in a live migration or with the VM powered off, it always fails. In the event log of the host these events are logged:

```
Source: Hyper-V-VMMS
Event ID: 16300
Cannot load a virtual machine configuration: General access denied error (0x80070005) (Virtual machine ID <GUID>)

Source: Hyper-V-VMMS
Evend ID: 20100
The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to register the configuration for the virtual machine '<GUID>' at 'C:\ClusterStorage\<PATH>\<VM>': General access denied error (0x80070005)

Source: Hyper-V-High-Availability
Event ID: 21102
'Virtual Machine Configuration <VM>' failed to register the virtual machine with the virtual machine management service.
```

All other VMs can be moved to/from the offending host, and the offending VM can be moved between the other two hosts. Also, this is not a storage problem, because there are other VMs in the same cluster volume, and the host has no troubles running them.

What's going on here?

Comment: LOLWUT?! I think your cluster is trolling you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never found the answer; it wasn't an ACL problem (file ACLs of the offending VM were identical to all other ones), probably something got stuck in the VM configuration.

Deleting the VM, re-creating it and re-attaching its VHDs completely fixed the problem.